# ORDER By Unix Timestamp DESC or ASC?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by, unix-timestamp

I have news items that when created adds the time of creation date/time in unix timestamp format into the database. If i wanted to order by most recent first would i use ASC or DESC in my mysql query?

### EDIT:

Thanks everyone for replying. I understand now. I will make **Sarfraz** answer the accepted solution as he was first to reply but thanks to everyone else to :) . Have to wait 11 minutes before i can accept it as a solution.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - I have not fully finished it yet and wanted to make sure before i went any further.

Comment: oh. just one word made you such a trouble. I wish you luck. Seems you'll need a lot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

DESC - timestamps are "higher = newer" number. So sorting by DESC(ending) will put the highest (newest) entries first.

Answer (score 6):

You should perform a SQL Query like below

```
SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

> If i wanted to order by most recent
>   first would i use ASC or DESC in my
>   mysql query?

You would order by `DESC` for the most recent info or higher date.

Answer (score 2):

Unix timestamp is number of seconds since the epoch (Dec. 1969).  So, newer posts have a higher number, thus, sort `DESC`.

Answer (score 2):

`DESC` will put the largest first, which would be the most recent.